# can I modify this to better way and fix this error

Tags: entity-framework

this is my code

```
  using (var conn = new DataEntities())
            {
                var query = from c in conn.servers where c.Servername != null select c;
                servers srv = query.FirstOrDefault();
                if (srv != null)
                {
                    Start.IPAddress = srv.ServerIP;
                    Start.ServerName = srv.Servername;
                    Start.GamePort = Convert.ToUInt16(srv.ServerPort);
                }
                Start.Servers.Add(Start.ServerName, Start.GamePort);
            }
```

servers srv = query.FirstOrDefault(); // error here

An unhandled exception of

```
type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
```

can write to usually better way ?

some suggestions i'm still beginner ^^
Thank you

Comment: What is the InnerException (`See the inner exception for details.`)?

Comment: here is {"Every derived table must have its own alias"}

Comment: It looks like you are using EF with MySQL, and MySQL is throwing that exception.

Comment: thanks for your reply 
well it's my query wrong i solve it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

```
using (var conn = new DataEntities())
            {
                var query = from c in conn.servers
                            select new
                            {
                                c.Servername,
                                c.ServerPort,
                                c.ServerIP
                            };
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Start.IPAddress = item.ServerIP;
                    Start.ServerName = item.Servername;
                    Start.GamePort = Convert.ToUInt16(item.ServerPort);
                }
                Start.Servers.Add(Start.ServerName, Start.GamePort);
            }
```